# Basic Authorization PHP with Server related

Tags: php, curl

I have some problem that related to HTTP_HEADERS in curl php in opencart. The code below is caller.

```
    $ch = curl_init();

    $url = 'http://aaa.com/index.php?route=common/home/getTotalCustomer';
    $url2 = 'http://bbb.com/index.php?route=common/home/getTotalCustomer';
    $url3 = 'http://ccc.com/index.php?route=common/home/getTotalCustomer';

    $header = array('Authorization:Basic ' . base64_encode('user:password'));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

    $results = curl_exec($ch);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(json_decode($results, true));
    echo '</pre>';
```

The receiver code like below:

```
public function getTotalCustomer(){
    $json = array();

    $this->load->model('account/customer');

    if(isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])){
        if(($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == 'password') && ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == 'user')){
            $json['total_customer'] = $this->model_account_customer->getTotalCustomer();
        }
    } else{
        $json['message'] = 'failed';
    }

    $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
}
```

I had tried in multiple domain with different servers. Some server can return the data but some server cannot return the data. Why?

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);`

Comment: change to this code cannot also..

Comment: Well, that is how basic auth is done. Maybe something else fails on those servers not able to respond? You will have to debug, so look into the http servers error log files.

Comment: How I look into the http servers error log files? Thanks

Comment: Em... by opening them and looking what they contain? You _do_ know what a log file is? And that http servers write log files? I mean how do you operate http servers without knowing about the log files?

Comment: u means the log files located in server whm dir?

Answer (score 0):

Your header that you're sending is incorrect.
You're passing
`Authorization:Basic <username:password>`
it should be
`Authorization: Basic <username:password>`
note the space.